# Appcelerator sei 6.0.2 macOS error to compile

Tags: module, appcelerator

I have problem with macOS and last version of appcelelerator SDK 6.0.2. I use module (my library stay under directory app/lib), I used the instruction `require` for instance but when I call the method it show me this error

> "undefined is not a function (evaluating
>   'Alloy.Globals.DatabaseRef.insertLastLogin(json.TipoLogin)')"

Anyone can help me about this error? It's a bug in new appcelerator version.. in version 5.5 I don't have this error.

Thanks for your support

Comment: Could you add your lib file in the question that has the method **insertLastLogin**. I don't think it has anything to do with the appcelerator version.

Comment: I've resolved the problem is Alloy.Globals.DatabaseRef = require('/database') i've add '/' before the instrunction was require('database')